# Stack limit exceeded due to repeated recursion

Tags: c, recursion, call, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

This code is to print the Fibonacci series using recursion. So I thought to devise a recursion instead of using iteration but as soon as I just execute the code and as soon as the value provider function is executed it is showing some error "segmentation error". I want to do it this way only... Can anyone  help? I'm just a beginner so please help and encourage me...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int n)
{
    int res;
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        res = fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2);
    return res;

}
int value_provider(int n)
{
    int choice1;
    if(n>=0)
    {
        choice1 = fibonacci(n-1);
        n -- ;
    }
    printf("%d",choice1);
    if(n>=0)
    {
        value_provider(n);
    }

}

void main()
{
    int n;
    printf("enter the number");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    value_provider(n);
}
```

This code is showing segmentation fault...
What can I do to remove it rather than changing the code?
I want to do it only this way; please help!

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to calculate the fibonacci of `-1` right?

Comment: Why is `value_provider` declared to return `int` when it has no `return` statement?

Comment: I don't think that the `value_provider` needs to be recursive.  Your current implementation of `fibonacci` is already recursive and calculates the fibonacci number of `n` correctly.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: Suggest `choice1 = fibonacci(n-1);` --> `choice1 = fibonacci(n);` for starters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `value_provider` function has poor terminating conditions.

- Don't try to calculate fibonacci of `-1` so n must be `>=1`
- Also once `n` is zero you need to finish the recursion, don't
  call `value_provider` again.

Try something more like this;

```
int value_provider(int n)
{
  int choice1=-1;
  if(n>=1)
  {
     choice1 = fibonacci(n-1);
     n -- ;
  }
  printf("%d ",choice1);
  if(n>0)
  {
    value_provider(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should also initialize `choice1`, so you don't get UB when the `if` fails.